# Display bug when moving a transparent window QtQuick

Tags: qt, qtquick2

So for my current project I need to use a transparent window.

On the creation of the window no problem it works is when you move the window that there is a problem.

The transparency does not apply because it considers that the window is part of the background and reproduces it in the new rendering.

I do not know if I'm very clear I put a picture in link it's more speaking sorry for the quality I had to take it with the laptop because when we capture it "refresh" the display and transparency becomes normal again.

Another surprising thing is that the transparency does not bug if what is behind is chrome ...

So basically the question is how to have a "normal" behavior?

Here I hope that you can help me I see no solution there.

At the code level:

main.cpp :

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView * view = new QQuickView;

    view->setTitle("Test");
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile ("main.qml"));
    view->setColor(Qt::transparent);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

main.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {

    width: 400
    height: 400
    color : "#00000000"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"
        width: 100
        height: 100
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: What version of Qt do you have ?, in Qt 5.12 in Linux works correctly

Comment: I use Qt 5.12 but i'm on Windows, i've tryed on Windows 10 and 8 same issue ...

Comment: Just looking at the captured image and not the code, it appears that the window is simply not being re-drawn. The fact that a capture "refreshes" the image and makes it look normal is further evidence that it is a redraw problem.